# Is there a way to detect if a UIView is touching another UIView? Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I have been developing a scrolling endless runner game (in Swift 4), and I want to detect if the player is touching a block/tile. Currently, I am using this code:

```
let centerX = Float(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width) / 2
for i2 in 0...tiles.count-1 {
    if scrollX + centerX > Float(tilePosition[i2][0] - 60) {
        if scrollX + centerX < Float(tilePosition[i2][0] + 60) {
            if Int(player.center.y) > tilePosition[i2][1] - blockFloatings[playerFrame] {
                if Int(player.center.y) < tilePosition[i2][1] + blockFloatings[playerFrame] {
                    while Int(player.center.y) > tilePosition[i2][1] - blockFloatings[playerFrame] {
                        playerGravity = 0
                        player.center.y = player.center.y - CGFloat(1)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code works, but it won't be accurate enough. I have rounded tiles such as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWK2Y.png), and also tiles with a wavy top like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f3Mn.png).

Right now, my code assumes the tile is a square, but sometimes it isn't. If the tile isn't a square, like the water, I want it so as you move right or left, the player moves up and down.

If you are going to answer this question, here are some things you would probably need to know about my current code:

`centerX` - The middle of the screen

`tiles` - The `UIImageView()` for the blocks/tiles

`scrollX` - The scroll in X

`tilePosition` - An array containing the positions of the blocks/tiles

`blockFloatings` - The player `UIImageView()` will be changing images, and each image is a different height. This array contains the numbers at which the player shouldn't fall through the ground (subtracting y-position)

`playerFrame` - The image ID of the player

`player` - The `UIImageView()` representing the player

`playerGravity` - The variable that states how fast the player should fall down each frame

**Edit:** You can also answer that there is no way possible.

Comment: You won’t get better collision detection with UIKit, at least not easily. If you want to detect collisions with custom shapes, you should take a look at `SpriteKit` and/or other game and physics engines.

Answer (score 4):

You could try using:

```
bool CGRectIntersectsRect(CGRect rect1, CGRect rect2);
```

by passing the player's frame and the tiles' frame as parameters.

Link to the documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1454747-cgrectintersectsrect

Comment: I think that OP stated in his question that he wanted something more accurate that simple frame intersection. Your suggestion to use `CGRectIntersectsRect` does look like an improvement, but it seems it doesn’t answer the question.